# UITableView with custom cell has two buttons and two labels

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uisearchbar

I am new for iphone app Development. i am suffering from this problem since two weeks.

I created uitableview with searchbar in uiviewcontroller class in xib.Here i am displaying table view with custom cell.In custom cell i created uistepper, three labels and a image in xib. here i am displaying image and a label to display profile image and text from dictionary.
the stepper for + and - functionality in custom cell.Now i want to display stepper action in label.when i click +button the label count will be 1 when i click - button the count will be 0 in same cell.i want to display button count in same cell.

can any one help me...

Thanks to all...

## viewcontroller.m

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
   static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ListOfProductsCell";
            
   ListOfProductsCell *cell = (ListOfProductsCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        
if (cell == nil) {
                   
   NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ListOfProductsCell" owner:self options:nil];
   cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
               
     productItemDit=[productListArry objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            NSString *offerStr= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",[[productItemDit objectForKey:@"offer"] floatValue]];
            NSString *fullCostStr=[[currencyCodeStr stringByAppendingString:@" "] stringByAppendingString:offerStr];
            NSLog(@"%@",fullCostStr);
            cell.itemCostLbl.text=fullCostStr;
            
            cell.itemStepper.tag=166;
            cell.itemAddedLbl.tag=122;
        
            cell.itemImg.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"profp.jpg"];
            
  }
      
    
         if (tableView == self.searchDisplayProduct.searchResultsTableView) {
                searchProductItemDit=[searchProductListArry objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
                NSLog(@"searchdit:%@",searchProductItemDit);
                cell.itemNameLbl.text= [searchProductItemDit objectForKey:@"name"];
                self.searchDisplayProduct.searchResultsTableView.separatorColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:200.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0];
            } else {
                productItemDit=[productListArry objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
                NSLog(@"dit:%@",productItemDit);
                cell.itemNameLbl.text=[productItemDit objectForKey:@"name"];
                
            }
        cell.itemAddedLbl =(UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:122];
        cell.itemAddedLbl.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d",itemCount];
        return cell;
```

}

ListOfProducts.m

```
//this method in custom class to get stepper action     
-(IBAction)itemValueChanged:(UIStepper *)sender
{
   ListOfProductsCell *clickedCell = (ListOfProductsCell *)[[sender superview] superview];
    double stepperValue = itemStepper.value;
     itemAddedLbl=(UILabel*)[clickedCell viewWithTag:122];
    itemAddedLbl.text=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%.f", stepperValue];
                
 }
```

when i use above its working perfectly.But when scroll the table view the value i added from stepper is disappear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this to add custom buttons or label and assign a tag to it `i.e. indexpath.row`

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }


      // Add  Custom Button 
        cellLikeBtn=[[UIButton alloc]init];
        cellLikeBtn.frame=CGRectMake(262, 5, 48,62);

        cellLikeBtn.backgroundColor=[UIColor whitecolor];
        cellLikeBtn.tag=indexPath.row;
        [cellLikeBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(Checktag:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:cellLikeBtn];
        [cellLikeBtn release];

    }
```

Now you will get t he tag for custom label or button.And you can make changes with that.

```
 -(IBAction)Checktag:(UIButton *)sender
    {
        NSLog(@"%d",sender.tag);
        UIButton* button = (UIButton *) sender;
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"abc.png"];
        [button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }
```

Replace button with label in your case.

I hope this will solve the issue.

You can use this as follows:

Assign your method at cellforRowAtIndexPath Like that

```
[cell.contentView addTarget:self action:@selector(Checktag:event:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

- (void)Checktag:(id)sender event:(id)event
{
    NSSet *touches = [event allTouches];
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentTouchPosition = [touch locationInView:self.tableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint: currentTouchPosition];

   NsLog("value of indePath.section %d ,indexPath.row %d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row);

}
```

Comment: hi abhishek, this is fine but what about tableview with more than one section. then it will be difficult to find which section button pressed. as indexpath.row would be same for multiple sections.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for reference. Make changes in this code as per your requirements. I have edited your code and tried not to make big changes. But seriously your code is unclear and messy. You can clean up your code and make it a lot better.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ListOfProductsCell";

        ListOfProductsCell *cell = (ListOfProductsCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ListOfProductsCell" owner:self options:nil]objectAtIndex:0];
        }

            productItemDit=[productListArry objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            NSString *offerStr= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",[[productItemDit objectForKey:@"offer"] floatValue]];
            NSString *fullCostStr=[[currencyCodeStr stringByAppendingString:@" "] stringByAppendingString:offerStr];
            NSLog(@"%@",fullCostStr);
            cell.itemCostLbl.text=fullCostStr;

            cell.itemStepper.tag=indexPath.row+indexPath.section+1;
            cell.itemAddedLbl.tag=indexPath.row+indexPath.section+101;

            cell.itemImg.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"profp.jpg"];

         if (tableView == self.searchDisplayProduct.searchResultsTableView) {
                searchProductItemDit=[searchProductListArry objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
                NSLog(@"searchdit:%@",searchProductItemDit);
                cell.itemNameLbl.text= [searchProductItemDit objectForKey:@"name"];
                self.searchDisplayProduct.searchResultsTableView.separatorColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:200.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0];
            } else {
                productItemDit=[productListArry objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
                NSLog(@"dit:%@",productItemDit);
                cell.itemNameLbl.text=[productItemDit objectForKey:@"name"];

            }
        cell.itemAddedLbl =(UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:indexPath.row+indexPath.section+1];
        cell.itemAddedLbl.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d",itemCount];
        return cell;
    }

-(IBAction)itemValueChanged:(UIStepper *)sender
{
   ListOfProductsCell *clickedCell = (ListOfProductsCell *)[[sender superview]  superview];
    itemAddedLbl=(UILabel*)[clickedCell viewWithTag:sender.tag+100];
     double stepperValue = sender.value;
    itemAddedLbl.text=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%.f", stepperValue];

 }
```

Comment: Thanks,i have only one section. i want to display stepper action in label. How..?

Comment: Check i have added a method. You can get some clue how to do that in simple and easy way.

Comment: when i used your code my entire cell is disappears from table view.its displaying only stepper value.

Comment: So who told you to use my code blindly.I can not test this. Just take some hints and modify your own code.

Comment: Please check my edit question. My code is working fine. But my problem is when i scroll the table view the stepper value is disappearing from cell.

Comment: Try to understand the code and modify it. Don't just copy and paste.

Comment: Okay that's happening because you are creating new cells everytime. So you can maintain an array that store stepper values and pass the values from that array in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: yes, you are right. cells is creating every time when i scroll the table view. the label getting null when i scroll. Can you help to over come this, to stop creating new cells ever time.

Comment: edit your question and show the code that is working fine for you